# Ruby, how to get a random number out of a specified group?

Tags: ruby, random

If I have a group of numbers like (0,3,6,9) how can I pull a random one out? Just to be clear, what if the group is not a multiple, any random group of numbers, but the chosen one can only be one of those that are in the group, not a range.

How would I need to provide the numbers? In an array? And how to use rand() to only use those specified?

This is what I'm doing right now, but is there a better way?

```
randomArray = [0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30]
=> [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30] 
id = rand(randomArray.length)
=> 5 
randomArray[id]
=> 15
```

Comment: Incidentally, in future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer (at least a couple of hours, say). Quick selections can discourage other answers and are not appreciated by others working on answers when the greenie flashes on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
a = [0,3,6,9]
```

you could write

```
a.sample          #=> 6
```

or

```
a[rand(a.size)]   #=> 3
```

Comment: thanks,  i just added that I was using that 2nd technique, is there another way or this is it? (btw, i'm loving `.sample`, thanks for that one!)

Comment: Those are the two standard ways. Note that [Array#sample](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample) takes an argument which is the number of elements you want to sample (which defaults to `1`).  If `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, `a.sample(5) #=> [6, 4, 1, 8, 9]`. That method samples *without* replacement*. To draw a sample of the same size *with* replacement: `5.times.map { a[rand 10] } #=> [3, 1, 9, 3, 4]`.

Comment: One (minor) variant would be if you know you want to sample all of the elements without replacement:  `a.shuffle.each {|e| ... }`